# How to read token from Braintree_PaymentMethod::create

Tags: php, braintree

What is the correct way of reading the return object from the Braintree_PaymentMethod::create call ? 
I would like to access the auto-generated token.

I am doing this currently:

    `$result = $output->paymentMethod->_attributes['token']`

I couldn't find it in the Braintree documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a snippet demonstrating how to retrieve the token from a successful payment method creation.

```
$result = Braintree_PaymentMethod::create(array(
    'customerId' => 'existing-customer',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => 'valid-nonce'
));

$token = $result->paymentMethod->token;
```

[More information about result objects](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/php/reference/general/result-objects)